# Find select index by value|text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it would be possible to get a `select` `object` `index` knowing its `value`.

Something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    ...
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

I have, let's say, value `68`, or text `Gonna`, and I would like to get the object index.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [*Attribute Equals Selector*](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
var val = "68";
var index = $('select option[value='+val+']').index();
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

**OR:** With [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) Selector

```js
var text = 'Gonna';
var index = $('select option:contains('+text+')').index();
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

**Update:** Solution when the element is in the variable with [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
var val = "68";
var itemSelect = document.getElementById('items');
var index = $(itemSelect).find('[value='+val+']').index()
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="items">
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Same as for your collegue over there. Thanks for your help. That's nice but (there's always a but!) what if I have the select already in a var and the value in another var? --> var itemSelect = document.getElementById('items');? Should I go for something like this: index = itemSelect.option(value).index();

Comment: @Oiproks, you can simply concatenate the selector with the variable....updated the answer....please check:)

Comment: @Oiproks, you can not use `index()` in pure JS as it is a jQuery method, please check the third solution in the updated answer with `find()`......thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Simply select element by [attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for value attribute i.e 68

or you can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector: for text i.e Gonna

and get its index by [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function.

Here is an example.

```js
let value = "68", text = "Gonna";
console.log($(`select>option[value='${value}']`).index());
console.log($(`select>option:contains('${text}')`).index());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's nice but (there's always a but!) what if I have the select already in a var and the value in another var? --> `var itemSelect = document.getElementById('items');`? Should I go for something like this: `index = itemSelect.option(value).index();`

Comment: @Oiproks thank you for your query, I have updated my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is the vanilla js version of other answers.

```js
var d = document.querySelector('select option[value="68"]').index;
console.log(d);
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Probably the shortest and only proper way to do this in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("option"), 0)
  .findIndex(function(element) {
    return element.value == 69
  })
);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="12">Never</option>
  <option value="68">Gonna</option>
  <option value="69">Gonna1</option>
  <option value="2">Give</option>
  <option value="99">You</option>
  <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

> alert '2'

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery you can give id to `select` tag,

```
<select id="select-list">
    <option value="12">Never</option>
    <option value="68">Gonna</option>
    <option value="2">Give</option>
    <option value="99">You</option>
    <option value="55">Up</option>
</select>
```

And you can use this Javascript code,

```
  function getIndex(value) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById('select-list');
    var optArray = selectList.children;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < optArray.length) {
      var opt = optArray[i];
      if (opt.value == value) return i;
      i++;
    }
    return null; // If value isn't exist
  }
```